# For which sizes are plain loads and store to global memory in CUDA atomic?

Tags: cuda, atomic

Are general reads and writes to global memory atomic in CUDA if:

- It is a 4 byte instruction? (I assume yes)
- It is a 8 byte or 16 byte instruction? (I assume yes)

Are at least on Kepler and Fermi general 4 byte reads and writes to global memory atomic on Warp level or 8/16 Byte instructions atomic on  half/quater Warp level if:

- All warp threads access the same 32-byte L2 transaction block?  (I assume yes)
- Warp threads access different 32-byte L2 transaction blocks but all warp threads access the same 128 byte L2 cache line? (I assume no)
- All warp threads accesss different L2 cache lines? (I assume no)

If any of those assumptions about the atomicness on warp level is correct, is there any method of harnessing this knowledge without risking the compability to future Compute Capabilites?

Comment: "atomic" doesn't apply to simple reads or writes. It applies to complete read-modify-write cycles.

Comment: @Roger Dahl: Writes and reads also can be non atomic or atomic. Imagine a four byte read operation, which is subdivided by the machine into four one byte reads which are executed one after another. Thus the data could be modified between the four reads. That's why the read operation would not be atomic.

Comment: read and write transactions to global memory occur only in multiples of 32 bytes. with respect to transactions between the SMs and the caches, transactions are also not subdivided into individual byte transactions.

Comment: @user3134920: Thanks, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3):

Reads and writes generally take place with respect to the caches.  By the time the transactions are issued to global memory, there is no guarantee of atomicity in the CUDA programming or memory model, unless `atomic` instructions are used.

For example, suppose a thread in a threadblock updates a 4-byte quantity in L2 on Kepler.  Now, another thread, in another warp, threadblock, *or kernel* could update just one of those 4 bytes, in the L2, before that cacheline gets evicted to global memory.  By the time the cacheline gets evicted to global memory, it may not represent what was written either by the original thread or even the second thread (for example if a third write came along...).

Keep in mind the L2 is a write-back cache, cannot be disabled, and is not bypassed by global reads and writes, except in the case of `atomic` instructions.

Comment: This question wasn't pointed at the CUDA programming guide, but how the hardware actually behaves. Furthermore in your simple example the writes would still be atomic. As I questioned the atomicness I meant something like this: Thread A writes float A(0xAAAA) to the same address as thread B float B (0xBBBB). Is the result guaranteed to be either float A (0xAAAA) or float B (0xBBBB), which would make the write atomic, or may it also be something like 0xAABB, which would be a non atomic write?

Comment: For simultaneous writes of the same size data to the same location from the same warp, it is guaranteed that only one write will end up in the location.  There is no subdivision of writes into byte transactions.  Which of the writes that "wins" is undefined.

Comment: You know, on second thought, I think this answer might be missing the point. The fact that what gets written back from the L2 cache might not be what a thread as written - such as 3 out of 4 bytes same, 1 byte different - is not in itself a problem with atomicity. It's just the state of the memory reflects a later point in a sequence - after the second thread (or third etc) has written as well. We're not talking about a read-then-write after all. But you can never observe the result of performing "half of the write".